How do i embed guage meter into A-frame ar scene but is not visible ar
I want to insert dynamically generated guage meter into ar as it visible in real environment.    

tried all the ways either it comes as camera overlay and disappear in some time or not visible, i want to it as in real environment without any disturbances. there some 3d guages also avaible. my doubt is shall i include 3d objects only in ar-scene in a-frame and please it is indeed required for to complete the project.
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>A-Frame AR with SVG Gauge</title>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/aframe-environment-component/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/gaugeJS/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                height: 100vh;
                background-color: #efefef;
            }
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <!-- Hidden SVG container -->
    <div id="gauge-svg-container" class="hidden"></div>
    
    <a-scene
        vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
        embedded
        arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; trackingMethod: best; sourceWidth: 1280; sourceHeight: 720;"
    >
        <a-assets>
            <img id="gauge-image" src="" />
        </a-assets>
    
        <a-entity gps-entity-place="latitude: 0; longitude: 0;" visible="false">
            <a-box
                id="aqi-box"
                color="white"
                opacity="0.9"
                depth="0.05"
                height="1"
                width="1"
                position="-1.5 0 -3"
                rotation="0 0 0"
                look-at="[gps-camera]"
            >
                <a-image src="#gauge-image" width="1" height="1" position="0 0 0.05"></a-image>
            </a-box>
        </a-entity>
    
        <a-camera gps-camera rotation-reader></a-camera>
    </a-scene>
    
    <script>
        // Gauge setup
        var opts = {
            angle: -0.25,
            lineWidth: 0.2,
            radiusScale: 0.9,
            pointer: {
                length: 0.6,
                strokeWidth: 0.05,
                color: '#000000'
            },
            staticLabels: {
                font: "15px sans-serif",
                labels: [0, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
                color: "#000000",
                fractionDigits: 0
            },
            staticZones: [
                { strokeStyle: "#00B050", min: 0, max: 50 },
                { strokeStyle: "#92D050", min: 51, max: 100 },
                { strokeStyle: "#FFFF00", min: 101, max: 200 },
                { strokeStyle: "#FF6500", min: 201, max: 300 },
                { strokeStyle: "#FF0000", min: 301, max: 400 },
                { strokeStyle: "#C00000", min: 401, max: 500 }
            ],
            limitMax: false,
            limitMin: false,
            highDpiSupport: true
        };
    
        // Create gauge
        var target = document.createElement('canvas');
        target.width = 200;
        target.height = 200;
        var gauge = new Gauge(target).setOptions(opts);
        gauge.maxValue = 500;
        gauge.setMinValue(0);
        gauge.set(125);
    
        // Convert canvas to SVG
        function canvasToSVG(canvas) {
            var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
            svg.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
            svg.setAttribute("width", canvas.width);
            svg.setAttribute("height", canvas.height);
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            img.onload = function() {
                var imgElement = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
                imgElement.setAttributeNS(null, "href", img.src);
                imgElement.setAttribute("x", 0);
                imgElement.setAttribute("y", 0);
                imgElement.setAttribute("width", canvas.width);
                imgElement.setAttribute("height", canvas.height);
                svg.appendChild(imgElement);
                document.getElementById('gauge-svg-container').appendChild(svg);
                updateGaugeImage();
            };
        }
    
        // Convert SVG to Data URL
        function svgToDataURL(svg) {
            var svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
            return 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svgString);
        }
    
        // Update gauge image in AR scene
        function updateGaugeImage() {
            var svgElement = document.querySelector('#gauge-svg-container svg');
            var dataURL = svgToDataURL(svgElement);
            document.querySelector('#gauge-image').setAttribute('src', dataURL);
        }
    
        // Generate SVG and update image
        canvasToSVG(target);
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>

i added html page where i want to show guage meter dynamically in AR scene in camera , its based on location targeting, and guage meter is not visible and i tried multiple ways but no use .

